# Config exception launching web app in production mode Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config, production

I am trying to launch a web app in production mode in ruby from an Oracle VM Ubuntu but apparently my database is not configured.
I wrote this snippet in order to try launching it in production mode:

```
export RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
export SECRET_KEY_BASE='the randomly generated secret key'
rails server --environment production
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
=> Booting Puma
 > Rails 5.1.7 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.bucket_list/log/production
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    90: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    ...

/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:246:
in `resolve_symbol_connection':' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] 
(ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

My database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

The config.eager_load is set as asked in the error message in my environments/* files and I don't understand why it says it is set to nil.
Do you have any clue on what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Both the ``eager_load`` and database adapter messages are what you get if you start a server with an unknown environment name (e.g., ``--environment bananas``). If you start the server with ``environment --development`` do things work like you expect?

Comment: I modified the run-production.sh file with development instead of production but it gives me the same exception. I can run the app in dev mode with the 'rails server' command tough. I think it has to do with the db. I did a db setup and an asset precompile.Thanks for helping.